# Заполнить массив спирально(начиная от центра по часовой стрелке)

Tags: c++, массивы

Написала программу, которая заполняет массив спирально, но против часовой стрелки. Размер массива  всегда нечетный. Не могу довести до ума.

**Скажите что нужно поменять?**

Вот код:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>

 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
     int n = 5;
     int arr[n][n];
     int z;
     int x = n / 2 + 1;
     int y = n / 2 + 1;
     int k = 0;
     for (z = 1; z < n*n + 1; z++)
     {
         arr[x-1][y-1] = z;
         cout << "arr[" << x-1 << "][" << y-1 << "] = " << z << endl;
         switch (k % 4)
         {
             case 0:
                 y++;
                 if ((x+1) == y)
                     k++;
                 cout << "done! 0  ";
                 break;
             case 1:
                 x--;
                 if((n - x + 1) == y)
                     k++;
                 cout << "done! 1  ";
                 break;
             case 2:
                 y--;
                 if((n - x) == (n - y))
                     k++;
                 cout << "done! 2  ";
                 break;
             case 3:
                 x++;
                 if (y == (n - x + 1))
                     k++;
                 cout << "done! 3  ";
                 break;
             default:
                 cout << "Oh, NO! Error!" << endl;
                 break;
         }
     }

     cout << endl;
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
         {
             cout << setw(4) << arr[i][j];
         }
         cout << endl;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

То есть должно получиться вот так:

```
21 22 23 24 25
20  7  8  9 10
19  6  1  2 11
18  5  4  3 12
17 16 15 14 13
```

Comment: Используйте отладчик.

Comment: На всякий случай, аналогичная задача уже была рассмотрена на ru.SO в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450354 и там есть ссылка на [красивые решения](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Spiral_matrix)

Answer (score 4):

В этом [аналогичном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450354/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8) есть мой ответ.

Если оставить в стороне присутствующие там мои рассуждения и обратиться только к коду, то код написан таким образом, что он легко позволяет заполнить массив по спирали независимо от количества элементов (четное или нечетное), легко читаем и легко модифицируем.

Этот код заполняет массив, начиная с 1 по внешнему "кругу" массива.
То есть значения, которыми заполняются элементы массива увеличиваются от 1 до N * N.

Из этого кода получить вашу спираль очень просто!

Достаточно изменять исходное значение инициализатора от N * N до 1, а заполнять элементы массива точно также, начиная с "внешнего круга" массива.

Если в том примере заполнение идет от точки с координатами [0][0] в направлении вправо, то чтобы получить вашу спираль, нужно идти от точки с координатами [0][N-1]  в направлении влево.

Только вместо массива я использовал в демонстрационной программе вектор, так как C++ не поддерживает массивы с переменной длиной, которые вы в своей программе используете.

Вот как может выглядеть программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

int main()
{    
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ";

        size_t n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;

        if ( !n ) break;

        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::vector<std::vector<int>> v( n, std::vector<int>( n ) );

        size_t i = 0, j = n - 1;

        int value = n * n;

        while (n != 0)
        {
            size_t k = 0;
            do { v[i][j--] = value--; } while ( ++k < n - 1);
            for ( k = 0; k < n - 1; k++ ) v[i++][j] = value--;
            for ( k = 0; k < n - 1; k++ ) v[i][j++] = value--;
            for ( k = 0; k < n - 1; k++ ) v[i--][j] = value--;

            ++i; --j; n = n < 2 ? 0 : n - 2;
        }

        for ( const auto &row : v )
        {
            for ( int x : row ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль следующий:

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 10

91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 
90 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 
89 56 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 66 
88 55 30 13 14 15 16 17 38 67 
87 54 29 12  3  4  5 18 39 68 
86 53 28 11  2  1  6 19 40 69 
85 52 27 10  9  8  7 20 41 70 
84 51 26 25 24 23 22 21 42 71 
83 50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 72 
82 81 80 79 78 77 76 75 74 73 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 9

73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 
72 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
71 42 21 22 23 24 25 26 51 
70 41 20  7  8  9 10 27 52 
69 40 19  6  1  2 11 28 53 
68 39 18  5  4  3 12 29 54 
67 38 17 16 15 14 13 30 55 
66 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 56 
65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58 57 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 8

57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 
56 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 
55 30 13 14 15 16 17 38 
54 29 12  3  4  5 18 39 
53 28 11  2  1  6 19 40 
52 27 10  9  8  7 20 41 
51 26 25 24 23 22 21 42 
50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 7

43 44 45 46 47 48 49 
42 21 22 23 24 25 26 
41 20  7  8  9 10 27 
40 19  6  1  2 11 28 
39 18  5  4  3 12 29 
38 17 16 15 14 13 30 
37 36 35 34 33 32 31 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 6

31 32 33 34 35 36 
30 13 14 15 16 17 
29 12  3  4  5 18 
28 11  2  1  6 19 
27 10  9  8  7 20 
26 25 24 23 22 21 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

21 22 23 24 25 
20  7  8  9 10 
19  6  1  2 11 
18  5  4  3 12 
17 16 15 14 13 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

13 14 15 16 
12  3  4  5 
11  2  1  6 
10  9  8  7 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

 7  8  9 
 6  1  2 
 5  4  3 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

 3  4 
 2  1 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

 1 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Что касается вашего кода, то помимо того, что не следует использовать массивы с переменным размером, так как они не совместимы со стандартом C++, то я вижу уже во втором case ошибку. Как я понимаю, в этом case индекс x должен быть увеличен, а не уменьшен так как следующий выводимый элемент должен быть расположен в строке ниже исходной строки.
К тому же в вашем подходе можно запутаться, когда имеешь дело не только с нечетным числом элементов массива, но и с четным числом элементов массива.

```
         case 0:
             y++;
             if ((x+1) == y)
                 k++;
             cout << "done! 0  ";
             break;
         case 1:
             x--;
            ^^^^^^
             if((n - x + 1) == y)
                 k++;
             cout << "done! 1  ";
             break;
```

Comment: А вот в GNU g++ (даже с опцией -std=c++98) вполне можно написать `int a[n][n];`. / По вашему это не C++?

Answer (score 1):

поменяйте местами `x` и `y`

```
 switch (k % 4)
 {
     case 0:
         x++;
         if ((y+1) == x)
             k++;
         cout << "done! 0  ";
         break;
     case 1:
         y--;
         if((n - y + 1) == x)
             k++;
         cout << "done! 1  ";
         break;
     case 2:
         x--;
         if((n - y) == (n - x))
             k++;
         cout << "done! 2  ";
         break;
     case 3:
         y++;
         if (x == (n - y + 1))
             k++;
         cout << "done! 3  ";
         break;
     default:
         cout << "Oh, NO! Error!" << endl;
         break;
 }
```