# алгоритм построения спирали из чисел

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть n квадратов, необходимо их расположить так чтобы числа(номера) записанные в каждом квадрате образовали возрастающую спираль начина с 1 ого.
пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Функция для отрисовки квадрата есть и она имеет такой вид:
`square(x, y, number);` где `x, y` левая нижня вершина квадрата,`number` соответственно номер (число) квадрата.
А начало координат (0, 0) это левая нижняя вершина квадрата с номером 1.

Можно заметить что на каждом цикле спирали количество чисел увеличивается на 8 тоесть (первый круг 1 2 3 4 кол=4 => следующий круг уже 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16  кол=12 и т.д.)
Как менять x и y чтобы получилась подобная спираль ?

Comment: Найдите кто-нибудь дубликат, а?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/450354/10105, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/455155/10105