# подскажите что происходит в этой строке кода return $y ? $w + s($h - 1, $w, $y - 1, $w - $x - 1) : $x;

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста что делает эта строка кода

```
return $y ? $w + s($h - 1, $w, $y - 1, $w - $x - 1) : $x;
```

где условие в этом тернарном операторе? $y = $w - $x - 1 (см.ссылку) я думал тут должно быть логическое условие... вот этот момент я не понимаю

тут в комментариях код целиком
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450464/372818

Comment: Происходит `неведомое`. Укажите хотя бы язык, на котором это написанно(судя по гаданиям на картах: если переменная `y=true`, то к переменной `w` добавляем значение функции `s`, иначе возвращаем переменную `x`)

Comment: сам не знаю) предполагаю php

Comment: А зачем вам тогда это? Вы же где-то это нашли)

Comment: Вот где код написан, там и есть ответ.

Comment: не вижу где там описание работы именно этой строки, подскажите

Comment: в чем именно тут вопрос-то ? представлен тернарный оператор и вызов функции с параметрами.

Comment: где условие в этом тернарном операторе? $y = $w - $x - 1 я думал тут должно быть логическое условие... вот этот момент я не понимаю

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Этот ответ не является ответом на вопрос, но является ответом на вопрос в комментарии (Так как в комментарии будет не читабельно) как `y` может быть `true` если `y` число:

```
var_dump(1 == true) . PHP_EOL;
var_dump('string' == true) . PHP_EOL;
var_dump('false' == true) . PHP_EOL;
var_dump('' == true) . PHP_EOL;
var_dump(0 == true) . PHP_EOL;
var_dump(false == true) . PHP_EOL;
var_dump(null == true) . PHP_EOL;
```

Результатом будет:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

`( ? : )` – сокращенная форма условия if-else. Приведённый код аналогичен такому:

```
if ($y==true) {
  return $w + s($h - 1, $w, $y - 1, $w - $x - 1);
} else {
  return $x;
}
```

Comment: спасибо!  но я не понимаю как $y может быть равен true? это же будет просто число $y = $w - $x - 1

Comment: @Luc динамическая типизация

Comment: @Luc В таком случае, условие будет истинно, если переменная $y не равна 0.

Comment: Большое спасибо! понял